# Perl variable in regex for finding expression in hash

Tags: regex, perl

I have a big hash with a lot of elements.

```
%my_hash = ();
# filling of %my_hash automaticly
$my_variable;
# set the value of $my_variable within a loop
```

Now I want to find the value of `$my_variable`within  `%my_hash`. I tried it with

```
if(grep {/$my_variable/} keys %my_hash){
    $my_new_variable = #here should be the element of %my_hash which makes the statement true
}
```

how to do that?

Edit: The problem is not the whole `$my_variable` will be find at `%my_hash`, e.g.

```
 $my_variable = astring
 $modules_by_path{"this_is_a_longer_astring"} = (something)
```

now I want to find this...

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you have in the hash?

Comment: for example: `$modules_by_path{some_file.c} = path/to/this/file` and `$my_variable = file` could be it for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking only for one particular key from `%my_hash`,

```
if (my ($my_new_variable) = grep /\Q$my_variable/, keys %my_hash) {

  ..
}
```

or

```
if (my @keys = grep /\Q$my_variable/, keys %my_hash) { .. }
```

if there are more keys which match specified regex. (use `\Q` prefix if `$my_variable` is not regex but literal string to be matched).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`, but you need to put it in *scalar context* to get the result you want. You also need to *escape* the contents of `$my_variable` if there's any chance that it contains any regex metacharacters.

This uses `\Q` to escape the non-alphanumeric characters, and leaves all the hash keys that match in `@matching_keys`. It's up to you to decide what to do if there's more than one match!

```
my @matching_keys = grep /\Q$my_variable/, keys %my_hash;
```

I suspect that there's a better way to do this. It's spoiling the whole point of hashes to search through them like that, and I think a better data design would help. But I can't say any more unless you describe your data and your application.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to match every key of your hash, you have to iterate through them in a loop as well. this is how i would do it, don't know if it is the most elegant way though:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    foo => 1,
    bar => 1,
    baz => 1,
);

my $variable = "bar";
my $new_variable;

for my $key (keys %hash){
    if ($key =~ /$variable/){
        $new_variable = $hash{$key};
    }
}
print $new_variable, "\n";
```

also, always try to write stuff like that with use strict; it will spare you of many classic mistakes.

Comment: first: of course using strict :) then -> I know this method, but is n't there any nicer method to find a part of one element in a hash?

Comment: i was saying that because in your example you declared you variables as $my_variable and that wouldn't work if you use strict;

Comment: this part of code isn't taking out of a programm, only be "mutatis mutandis"

Comment: sorry i thought you just needed to have any way to solve this, and this way is very easy to understand. the other answers have given plenty of other ways to do this already.